# UISearchController black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have looked at other answers to this problem but they did not solve my problem.

This is my storyboard setup:
[image]

In my UITableViewController, if I set `self.definesPresentationContext = true` then the search bar will appear on every tab. If I don't, then the table will turn black after clicking search then switching to another tab and switching back.

Workaround 1: Dismiss searchController or set isActive to false in `viewWillDisappear`.

Problem: The search bar gets push down from the top every time I switch back and forth: [image]

Workaround 2: Set `searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true`.

Problem: In my other tab which also uses `UISearchController`, it's not able to present the scope due to another search bar being already present (but hidden):
 `Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x7ff81ac0aa30> on <xxx.ViewController: 0x7ff81ac0a6f0> which is already presenting (null)`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and was fixed, handling correctly the `definesPresentationContext` properly, so I just define this property to true in `viewDidAppear` and set it `false` in `viewWillDisappear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if(self.searchController == nil)
        {
            self.setupSearchBar()
        }else{
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
        }
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.searchController!.isActive = false
    self.searchController!.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
    self.definesPresentationContext = false
    if(self.showingSearchBar)
    {
        self.rigthNavBarButtonAction()
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(  Do you have a minimal app of it working?

Comment: @James i can do one for you but maybe is better option if you share with me your repo in github and i review and adjust your code what you think about?

Comment: It's only 2 files so i'll just link the paste https://pastebin.com/raw/udi52aK8, storyboard source: https://pastebin.com/raw/57zVjN8L. The storyboard is basically the default tabbed application template with secondviewcontroller changed to a tableviewcontroller, and cell reuse identifer "cell".

Tested on iPhone 7S simulator, XCode 8.3.3.

Comment: @James ok, i will review it

Answer (score 0):

Using your Workaround 1, setting `self.searchController!.isActive = true` in `viewDidAppear` does the magic. You'd also need to restore the search bar text though.